# knitr: Chapter name is the name of R chunk code

Tags: r, latex, knitr, sweave

I want to use the R chunk code output as the Chapter Name but could not figured out how to do this. Below is my minimum working example.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\chapter{cat(
<< label=Test1, echo=FALSE, results="asis">>=
2+1
@
)
}

Chapter name is the output of R chunk Code.

\end{document}
```

Comment: for `Sweave` format I think you want to use `Sexpr{}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me

```
<< label=Test1, echo=FALSE>>=
cn <- 2+1
@

\chapter*{Chapter \Sexpr{cn}}
```

Comment: Thanks @Roman for your nice answer. I would highly appreciate if you guide me how to run this code properly. `<< label=Test1, echo=FALSE>>=
library(noamtools)     # install_github("noamtools", "noamross")
cn <- help_console(topic=lm, format = "text", lines=1)
@

\chapter{\Sexpr{cn}}`
Looking forward to your help. Thanks

Comment: You have to type {Chapter \Sexpr{cn}}`, @MYaseen208.

Answer (score 2):

In RMarkdown you can use the following code

```
# `r I(1+2)`
```

Comment: I was thinking about Rmarkdown their `\Sexpr{...}` is `r ...`
and it works with Rmd. Didn't think it throu...
Edited my answer accordingly